# Devexpress C# XtraGrid Single Cell Edit Issues

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm about to pull my hair out for something that is probably very simple.

This is using the XtraGrid.

Let's assume I have two columns and x number of rows, contained in one column is just a checkbox that I set with the columnedit property and the other is a value. I have a text box set to be the editor of this second value.

How can I set this up so that if I check the checkbox for that row, it will allow editing to the number in the value field next to it? I have the allowedit set to true for the checkbox column, but if I set the allowedit to true for the 2nd column in say the checkbox checkedchanged event handler, it will allow all of the cells in that column to be edited. I have no other properties like readonly set or anything like that.

How can I distinguish between a single cell in that column and activate the editor while leaving the others readonly based on that checkbox in the same row? I have a feeling it involves using ShowingEditor and CustomRowCellEdit, but I'm not sure how to set that up.

Could someone take me through what I would need to do in order to accomplish this? What settings do I need to put for the readonly/allowedit properties for this column and what would I need to put in those ShowingEditor/CustomRowCellEdit methods to do this? I'm really new at this so it is probably a really basic question, but I need some help! Some code examples for C# to determine which cell is selected would help me, but I just need to figure this out. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you disable the editor in the second column when it shows up depending on the first column value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your are right, you have to manage this by implementing the `ShowingEditor` Event

This code for demonstration porpuses:

**First** I bond the `gridview1` to a `RandomClass`

```
public class RandomClass
{
    public bool AllowEdit { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public randomClass()
    {
        this.AllowEdit = true;
        Text = "Text1";
    }
}
```

then implement the `ShowingEditor` Event, Every time the `gridview1` tries to open the editor for the `second column` it checks whether `AllowEdit` column checked or not and take action according to it

```
private void gridView1_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
     if (gridView1.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Text"
          && !IsAllowingEdit(gridView1, gridView1.FocusedRowHandle))
     {
       e.Cancel = true;
     }
}

private bool IsAllowingEdit(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view,int row)
{
     try
     {
        bool val = Convert.ToBoolean(view.GetRowCellValue(row, "AllowEdit"));
        return val;
     }
     catch
     {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's a few days later, but thanks for your response. I modified your code slightly and got it working!